# migrate AngularJs app from Webpack to Vite

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, webpack, vite

I have an AngularJs app combined with React that I'm trying to migrate from Webpack 4 to Vite.
The majority of the app is AngularJs and recently we started "injecting" React components, until we switch completely to React.
I know Vite supports React (plugins etc.), but is there a way to use it with AngularJs?

After extensive research I still haven't found an answer, and AngularJs is deprecated so I guess no new support will come out.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/xlts-dev/angularjs-material-vite depends on the secret XLTS version of Angular. But it's still a goldmine of tips for using AngularJS with Vite.

(I'm migrating from Gulp!)